# How to add version number to CSS/JS files in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I would like to add versioning for my angular application to avoid cache like `style.css?ver=1` ? Where should I add that in `angular-cli.json`?

Comment: Doesn't `ng build --prod` already append hash to your assets for that purpose?

Comment: I have this configuration here so I should be able to add like this? ```"styles": [
        "assets/styles/app.scss?ver=123",
        "assets/styles/fonts.scss?ver=123"
      ]```

Comment: That's not how you do it with angular cli. When you `ng build --prod` the tool will compile your assets with a hash of each asset and then append it to the filename for you, updating the imports. You don't have to do _anything_ to manage this yourself.

Comment: For example, I also have a `styles.scss` file in my global styles. When I build in development mode, I get a `styles.css` file. With `ng build --prod`, webpack produces `styles.7c4c51d1276ebd077169.bundle.css` which is generated based on the file's contents, so you can cache it forever.

Comment: I am sorry I am a beginner to angular4. We are facing issues with cache for our web application. I have a question in the the index.html in production, The script tags looks like `<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>` and also styles `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/fonts/style.css">`  It doesnt show any version number.

Comment: It's ok, everyone starts somewhere. :) What is the exact command you are using right now to build for production? You asked about `.angular-cli.json`, so I assume you're using that.

Comment: At the moment we are using `ng build`. I will change it to ng build --prod and see whether it will be able to hash the css/js links

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158549/discussion-between-msanford-and-harsha-kakumanu).

Comment: @msanford Thanks for your prompt response this got fixed by using `ng build --prod`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `ng build --prod`, it will hash your assets and modules and append the hash to the file name.

You have nothing to manage manually.

Comment: How can we add version number in URL for css and js? Can we automate it for all html files in build process? <script src="/js/app.<version-no>.js"></script>

Comment: @Nitul Like I said, using `ng build --prod` does _all_ of that for you (provided that the assets are part of your angular application). See my comments on the original post. Using "version numbers" is an antiquated idea that was only useful when it was managed by human brains who needed to remember what was going on. A hash is better, and is completely automatic.